# How to use GTK+ with ada

Tags: gtk, ada

Anyone can show me some examples, simple, how to use GTK with Ada?
examples, like: How to use Glade with Ada, create an simple window....

an simple window, like this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

And, It's possible to use GtkMM, with ada ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few of my favorite [GtkAda](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/gtkada/) programs:

- [Animation demo](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/gtk/lady.html)
- [Linxtris](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linxtris/)
- [Mine Detector](http://pragmada.home.mchsi.com/mindet.html)

Also, don't overlook the `examples` and `testgtk` folders of [GtkAda](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/gtkada/) itself.

Additional resources:

- [GTK+ API Documentation](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php)
- [Rosetta Code Category: Ada](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aAda)
- [Glade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer)

Comment: and have a look at the `examples` folder