# Chat window with Gtk+

Tags: gtk, ada

I'm writing some sort of chat in *Ada* using *Gtk+* (technically *GtkAda*). And I have of problem with some *Gtk*. My window consists of an `Entry`, `TextView` and `Button` ("Send").

The hard part is in handler `On_Button_Send_Clicked` (procedure that deals with signal 'clicked' on button). I want to read text form `Entry` and place it in `TextView`, but how can I access `TextView` and `Entry` from  a procedure that has only access to `Button`, as I connect the signal with a handler in this way:

```
package Handlers is new Gtk.Handlers.Callback
    (Widget_Type => Gtk_Widget_Record);

procedure On_Button_Send_Clicked
    (Object : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class);
...

Handlers.Connect
   (Button, "clicked", Handlers.To_Marshaller (On_Button_Send_Clicked'access);
```

**My question is**: are there any methods like `Get_Gtk_Entry` or `Get_Text_View`, which would be the simples way? Or is there another way, but still simple?

I have also come across a solution in which I declare a record:

```
type Widget_Collection_Record is new Glib.Object.GObject_Record with record
    Terminal   : Gtk.GEntry.Gtk_Entry;
    Text_Field : Gtk.Text_View.Gtk_Text_View;
end record;
```

and make the callback this way:

```
package Widget_Collection_Cb is new Gtk.Handlers.Callback
    (Widget_Type => Widget_Collection_Record);

procedure On_Button_Send_Clicked
    (Object : access Widget_Collection_Record'Class);
```

But now I have another question: how do I connect a signal from a `Button` with a handler, since the widget `Button` is not a part of my `Widget_Collection_Record`?

I'm not sure whether I sound clear...

So please, if you know something that may solve my problem, please post - it could be C, C++, Python - I'll try to convert it to Ada ;D

## And the summary of my problem is:

How can I write a handler to read from an `Entry` and write on a `Text_View` when a `Button` clicked?

**Edit**: Question closed. I'm aware that it's not clear what I asked for, and that's way I've chosen the way to pass record of `User_Data` to callback... and now my new problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924540/gtkada-simple-chat-error)

Comment: If you don't get an aswer here, you can try at comp.lang.ada, some knowledgeable GtkAda developers hang out there.

Comment: Preparing an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be helpful, too.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6755172/230513).

Comment: See also this [example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/GUI_component_interaction#Ada).

Comment: Thanks trashgod for this is really nice example ;D Btw: Do you know another example with gtk.builder and even gtkada.builder, because I'm also having trouble with this (and /testgtk/create_builder.adb helps just that litte)

Comment: I updated this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6755172/230513) with a link for `glade`; the generated Ada source may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use this reference : http://www.univ-orleans.fr/sciences/info/ressources/webada/doc/gtkada/gtkada_rm/index.html

You didn't provide much informations about the organization of your project.
But if you have a simple procedure where you declare everything then :

```
procedure foo is
    -- variables
    E : GTk_GEntry;
    T : Gtk_Text_View;
    ...
    procedure On_Button_Send_Clicked (Object : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class) is
    begin
       S : String := Get_Text (E);
       B : Gtk_Text_Buffer := Get_Buffer (T);
    begin
       Set_Text (B, S);
       ...
    end On_Button_Send_Clicked;
begin
   ...
   Handlers.Connect
      (Button, "clicked", Handlers.To_Marshaller (On_Button_Send_Clicked'access);
   ...
end foo
```

Comment: As far as I remember, the problem was that I couldn't reach Text_View, because I didn't have any Text_View variable inside Btn_clicked handler. (There was no Text_View in this scope) But after all I based my app on gtk_bulder, and using that engine I was able to reach any object of the window. Anyway thanks for the answer, though 5 months after the question have been asked is kinda a long time =P