# GtkAda simple chat error

Tags: gtk, ada

I'm writing simple chat program in Ada, and I'm having problem with chat window simulation - on button clicked it reads text form entry and puts it on text_view. Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/1639279) I've written and here is the compile output:

```
gnatmake client `gtkada-config`
gcc -c -I/usr/include/gtkada client_pkg.adb
client_pkg.adb:14:19: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
client_pkg.adb:14:37: expected private type "Gtk_Text_Iter" defined at gtk-text_iter.ads:48
client_pkg.adb:14:37: found type "Gtk_Text_View" defined at gtk-text_view.ads:58
client_pkg.adb:14:37:   ==> in call to "Get_Buffer" at gtk-text_buffer.ads:568
client_pkg.adb:14:37:   ==> in call to "Get_Buffer" at gtk-text_buffer.ads:407
client_pkg.adb:15:34: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
client_pkg.adb:15:34: missing argument for parameter "Start" in call to "Get_Text" declared at gtk-text_buffer.ads:283
client_pkg.adb:15:34: missing argument for parameter "Start" in call to "Get_Text" declared at gtk-text_buffer.ads:270
gnatmake: "client_pkg.adb" compilation error
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem, since I have no idea why procedure `Get_Buffer` expects `Gtk_Text_Iter`, and why `Get_Text` miss Start parameter?

Comment: It might be good to update your original question, [Chat window with Gtk+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877873/chat-window-with-gtk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the correct procedures/functions.

In your example, you call `Gtk.Text_Buffer.Get_Buffer`, not the correct `Gtk.Text_View.Get_Buffer`. This is because you `with` and `use` Gtk.Text_Buffer, but don't `use` Gtk.Text_View. You should be careful what you `use`. Same for Get_Text.

If you add `use` clauses for Gtk.Text_View and Gtk.GEntry, those errors should disappear.

But I give you an advice: try to use as few as possible `use` clauses. That way you always know what function is really called.

**TLDR:** Add `use Gtk.Text_View; use Gtk.GEntry;` to the declaration part of the `On_Btn_Send_Clicked` procedure.